# Implement prev/next article

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm fetching some articles from the web. I load them into array and pass them into DetailViewController, and I have 2 buttons - same like Mail, you press the ^ and you go to the next article.

Right now I do it by getting the next object of this array with objects.

But is this the most efficient way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  (Unless you want to change your user interface, in which case you might want to consider swiping left and right instead of pressing a button.)